# Is there a R function to sign a value when it is equal to its 5 previous values?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe and I have to check  If its one column has not changed during the last 60 minutes (each 10 minutes I have a data point) SO I have to flag the corresponding data point `Ti` as bad data point (if data point `Ti` plus 5 data points before from `Ti−1` to `Ti−5` are equal)  . how can I do that?

Comment: You might enjoy using the `rle` function:   look at  `rle(df[,column_number])$lengths` to find runs of greater than 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.table::rleid` is very useful for things like this:

```
## sample data
d = data.frame(x = c(1, 2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, 4,4,4 2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(rleid = data.table::rleid(x)) %>%
  mutate(bad_flag = row_number() > 5)
# # A tibble: 18 x 3
# # Groups:   rleid [5]
#        x rleid bad_flag
#    <dbl> <int> <lgl>   
#  1     1     1 FALSE   
#  2     2     2 FALSE   
#  3     2     2 FALSE   
#  4     3     3 FALSE   
#  5     3     3 FALSE   
#  6     3     3 FALSE   
#  7     3     3 FALSE   
#  8     3     3 FALSE   
#  9     3     3 TRUE    
# 10     3     3 TRUE    
# 11     4     4 FALSE   
# 12     4     4 FALSE   
# 13     2     5 FALSE   
# 14     2     5 FALSE   
# 15     2     5 FALSE   
# 16     2     5 FALSE   
# 17     2     5 FALSE   
# 18     2     5 TRUE
```

This does assume that your measurements are not floating point numbers (integers are fine). If they are floating points, you may need to round them to be safe.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Please read the comments to this post. The authors make excellent points to this answer.**

A straighforward solution might be

```r
### your df ...
df <- ...

get.previous.five.indexes(idx)
{
     to.substract <- 1:5

     return(idx - to.substract)
}


for (idx in 6:nrow(df))
{
     previous.five.indexes <- get.previous.five.indexes(idf)

     current.value   <- df$my.value[idx]
     previous.values <- df$my.value[previous.five.indexes]

     df$flag[idx]    <- isTRUE(all.equal(previous.values, row["value"]))
}
```

If you want to avoid a `for` loop, you can also use `apply`.

```r
df <- ...

get.previous.five.indexes(idx)
{
     to.substract <- 1:5

     return(idx - to.substract)
}


df$idx <- 1:nrow(df)

df$flag <- apply(df,
                 margin = 1,
                 fun = function(row)
                 {
                      if (row["idx"] < 6)
                      {
                           return(FALSE)
                      }

                      previous.five.indexes <- get.previous.five.indexes(row["idx"])

                      previous.values <- df$my.value[previous.five.indexes]

                      return(isTRUE(all.equal(previous.values, row["value"])))
                 })
```

HTH

Comment: A couple comments - I think by subtracting negative numbers you're actually adding - `to.subtract <- 1:5` should be better. And with recycling I think you can skip the `rep_len`,  `idx - 1:5` will return the same value if `idx` is length 1 as if you repeat it. Similarly you can use `all(previous.values == current.value)`. Though if you do use `all.equal`, heed the warning in the help file: *"Do not use `all.equal` directly in if expressions—either use `isTRUE(all.equal(....))` or `identical` if appropriate."*

Comment: To add to @GregorThomas warning: whatever comparison you use, if your inputs are numeric (non-integer), you have to set a "limit' on how different they can be and still be considered the same value.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Excellent point! Thank you! How does `data.table::rleid ` handle that?

Comment: The `rleid` approach doesn't handle that at all - just added a caveat to my answer pointing that out. `all.equal` *does* handle that well, but you would want to wrap it in `isTRUE` as the help page suggests. (It doesn't return `FALSE` for non-equal inputs, see `all.equal(3, 4)`.)

Comment: But one other code simplication, `if(all(...)) {return(TRUE)} else{return(FALSE)}` is a long way to write `return(all(...))`.

Comment: And this is not a good use of `apply`, which is made for matrices. `sapply` would be a better choice, probably.

Comment: Acoording to documentation, `sapply` is just a wrapper around `lapply`.

Comment: @MacOS the man page says it works like `rle` (probably my alltime favorite tool ), which suggests it expects to be working with char or integer values in the first place.  Hence GregorT's warnings about `all.equal` .     FWIW,  my package  `cgwtools::approxeq` may be a more "friendly" tool than `all.equal`

Comment: @MacOS yes, `lapply` would also work (though it would return a `list`, `sapply` will automatically simplify to a vector in this case). `sapply` or `unlist(lapply(...))` would be fine choices here. `apply` is worse here, because `apply` is made for matrices.

Comment: [This FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/903061) is very helpful in understanding the different *apply functions and when they should be used.